# moving mutiple files from one folder to another using python

Tags: python

I have a “.txt ”file which consists of various filenames and I want to search each filename in a source_folder where these files are actually kept and I want to move the matching files to a specific folder.
Source_folder contain files within multiple folders.

My .txt file looks like this:

```
ant1.aiq
ant2.aiq
ant3.aiq
ant4.aiq
```

I want to match each line of my textfile (`ant1.aiq`, `ant2.aiq` and so on) with filenames which are present at some specific place (`R:\Sample`) and extract matching files into some other place (`R:\sample\wsa`).

So far I have written following code but it doesnt work:

```
import os
import shutil

sourceDir = "R:\test_vectors\pxi_wcdma"
targetDir = "R:\\Sample\\wsa"
existingFiles = set(f for f in os.listdir(sourceDir) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(sourceDir, f)))
infilepath = "aiq_hits.txt"
with open(infilepath) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        fname = line.strip()
        if fname not in existingFiles: continue
            shutil.move(os.path.join(sourceDir, fname),os.path.join(targetDir, fname))
```

Path for source folder is :
R:\test_vectors\pxi_wcdma
pxi_wcdma folder contains .aiq files which are to be copied

Comment: Are you getting an error? Also, please post a few lines from a source file.

Comment: I am not getting any error but files are not moved from source folder to destination folder

Comment: You should escape the backslash as \\ in `sourceDir`. Currently a tab `\t` is part of your filename. An even better solution would be to use [raw strings](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals)

Comment: @halex:ok but that change doesnt seem to work

Comment: Code says `for line in infile:`. Are the filenames in `aiq_hits.txt` really one to a line (unlike your sample above)? If not, you need to read in the file, `split()` the filenames apart, and iterate through those.

Comment: @bahmait: yes each line has only one filename

Comment: instead of `continue` try `print fname` and see if that tells you more about what's going on. Print out `existingFiles` too and make sure it looks like you think it should look etc.

Comment: @MayankJain Changing `sourceDir = "R:\test_vectors\pxi_wcdma"` to `sourceDir = r"R:\test_vectors\pxi_wcdma"` (notice the added `r` before the opening `"` to make it a raw string) and get rid of the wrong indentation of `shutil.move(os.path.join(sourceDir, fname),os.path.join(targetDir, fname))` works for me

Comment: @halex: the indentation is correct I presume

Comment: @MayankJain No it's not. Your if currently has one statement `continue` and the `shutil...` one shows error wrong indentation

Comment: @MayankJain not the way you have it above, no.

Comment: @halex :alright but it still doesnt work .

Comment: could you please help me out with some other code if possible..

Comment: @MayankJain Could you edit your question with the exact code you are now using.

Comment: @MayankJain: If you want help with some other code ask a new question. But let's get this one fixed first.

Answer (score 3):

I've tested this on my server and it works. 
Make sure the paths are correct and you've permissions to read and write.

```
import os
import shutil

file = "test.txt"
sourceDir = "R:\\test_vectors\\pxi_wcdma\\"
targetDir = "R:\\Sample\\wsa\\"

for line in open("test.txt") :
    line =  line.rstrip('\n')
    if os.path.isfile(sourceDir+line):
        shutil.move(sourceDir+line, targetDir+line)
```

---

Some tips about path names on windows OS:

This works both in linux and windows:

```
'C:/mydir'
```

Other posibility is :

```
'C:\\mydir'
```

If you have problems with some names you can also try raw strings:

```
r'C:\mydir'
```

Comment: this did not work  for me.I dont know why files are not getting moved.